# Compute rendering time in a Qt5 QML Application

Tags: qml, qt5

I am using QT5 alpha for developing a QML app for a linux based tablet. The app gets slow upon having a certain number of qml widgets. I need to know how much time is spent to render each frame. Which component performs the rendering of the qml scenegraph and how can I compute frame time?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to checkout `qtdeclarative` module. Rendering class is in `src/quick/scenegraph/coreapi/` check `qsgdefaultrenderer.cpp`. However it may not help, because scenegraph renders everything at once. Each QML item is translated into much simplier nodes. Those nodes then combined into a list and then whole list is rendered. You may want to use QML profiler which comes with QT Creator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the QML profiler in Qt Creator?  In addition to rendering time it displays the cost of binding evaluation, component creation, and signal handling.